# Need help: xpath query

Tags: parsing, xpath

i want to exclude the IMG Values in this table:

```
<table class="info">
 <tbody>
  <tr><th class="round-top" colspan="2">Status</th></tr>  
  <tr class="even">
    <td class="key">Schaltprogramm aktiv</td>
    <td class="value"><img height="15" src="./pics/ste-symbol_an-97b765.png"></td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to exclude the values in this table:

```
<table class="info">
 <tbody>
  <tr><th class="round-top" colspan="2">Warmwasser</th></tr>  
  <tr class="even">
    <td class="key">WW-Isttemp.</td>
    <td class="value">49,0 °C</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="odd">
    <td class="key round-leftbottom">WW-Solltemp.</td>
    <td class="value round-rightbottom">46,5 °C</td>
  </tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Here are my poorly test:

```
$nodelist = $xpath->query( "//tr/td[substring(@class,1,5)='value']" );
$imgs = $xpath->query("//table[@class='info']/tr/td/img");
```

What must i do to exclude the IMG Values in the variable "nodelist"?

Any idea?

Comment: XPath is a *query* language for XML documents. As such, an XPath expression cannot alter a document (by creating or deleting nodes). What you need to do is *transform* the document into another XML document. XSLT is a language especially designed for XML transformations -- and this specific wanted transformation is trivial to achieve with XSLT. Will you be interested in getting an XSLT solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think (but am not certain) that you want `$nodelist` to contain all the `td` elements whose `class` attribute begins with the string `value` *but not if they contain an `img` element*.

If that's a correct interpretation of your question, change

```
$nodelist = $xpath->query( "//tr/td[substring(@class,1,5)='value']" );
```

to

```
$nodelist = $xpath->query( "//tr/td[substring(@class,1,5)='value'][not(img)]" );
```

I'm not clear what it is you want to do about the temperature values in your second sample table; you might want to edit the question to make clearer whether you want to retrieve them or not.